# Is IFC 4 supported in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

We integrated Autodesk Forge in our platform to allow customers to view their models online. However, when customers upload IFC V4 Files (specifically V 4.0), there is an error message shown complaining over a missing model, although the file is valid. Other viewer such as BIM Collab Zoom render the model without problems. Question is (and I was not able to find this answer online) which IFC versions are supported in the Forge ecosystem?
If V4 is not supported, are there any plans in the near future to support it? The documentation at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/ only generally mentions the IFC support, but no versions.

Comment: IFC should be supported, if you're having problems, are you able to share a non-confidential sample file? Please send to forge.help at autodesk.com

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @AugustoGoncalves, I will send a sample as you said

Comment: A quick question @hackingSminion, Which IFC translation pipeline are you using? Only modern IFC translation pipeline support IFC4 translation. You need to submit the job with the option `"advanced.conversionMethod": "modern"`, see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure) for details.

Comment: and it supports IFC4 reference view 1.0 only currently.

Comment: Thank you @EasonKang for your reply. We now tried both pipelines and played around with different other parameters as well. Sadly the model, while it is now getting rendered, is not displayed correctly. some elements seem to be missing while others are somehow displayed twice, once at a random position. I'd be happy to provide samples and screenshots to the email adress that was provided above, should i do that? as a side note, we think it would be a great convience if your API could determine itself which pipeline should get used in the future, this would make it much simpler to use

Comment: Hi @hackingSminion, it's hard to tell what happened. So, yes! Please consider sharing non-confidential sample models and snapshots to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` for future investigation.

Comment: Thank you very much @EasonKang, will do so